# jruby on tomcat - RackInitializationException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby

After following http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JrubyOnRailsOnTomcat#Rails_2.0
though with tomcat 5.5, jruby 1.3.0, rails 2.3.2

tomcat gives:

SEVERE: unable to create shared application instance
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: Please install the jdbc adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbc-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/jdbc_adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

needed to do the following ...

gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
gem install jruby-openssl

uncomment the following line from warble.rb

```
config.gems += ["activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "jruby-openssl"]
```